# Unix File Permissions and Decryption with OpenSSL's enc command

Tags: permissions, encryption

I have a specific question about OpenSSL's enc command, but I suppose it applies more generally to Unix/Linux file permissions. I have a bash script which has the following decrypt command:

openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in secret.enc -out secret -pass file:./pass.bin

I understand if the file permission for pass.bin is set to 700, it's essentially full permission for the owner, and permission denied for everyone else. The bash script that contains the decrypt command (let's just call it "script") is also set to 700 such that it can only be executed by the owner. My understanding then, presuming that I'm not the owner of either files, is that if I attempt to read "script" or "pass.bin", I would get a "permission denied" response. However, what happens if I run the decrypt command in the command line? Will this still result in a decrypted "secret" file?

Comment: The question could probably benefit if you left OpenSSL out of it. This is not an OpenSSL question

Comment: Yes, I did state that this applies more generally to file permissions. My use case happens to be with OpenSSL and the forum encourages you to be as specific as possible so...

Comment: On the other hand we favour succinct questions and direct to the point questions. The fact that you are not used to the Unix security model does not mean it has something to do with OpenSSL

Comment: Cool, well given my account name, I think my familiarity with Unix/Unix-like security models can be inferred. I appreciate your help anyway, though.

Comment: You might want to rethink using openssl's `enc` command, last I read [it's non-standard in a few ways, uses MD5 & only 1 iteration for it's non-standard and not-well vetted key derivation function & lets someone "try" several dozens of millions of potential passwords per second (hundreds of millions will be achievable with a GPU)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247821/openssl-vs-gpg-for-encrypting-off-site-backups]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that this happens to be an OpenSSL command is not important.

The script is not readable by anyone but the owner (and root, let's not forget that).  This means that a non-owner can't execute it as `./script.sh` or run it with e.g. `bash script.sh`.

Had the script been readable, a non-owner would be able to run it, but the decryption, requiring the `pass.bin` file, would not succeed (since it's not readable by the non-owner).  This is also what would happen if you ran the decryption in the shell as a non-owner of the `pass.bin` file.

To convince yourself about these things, set up a new user and try it to see what happens.